# How to save a List of type map into firestore, and then read/write to the created maps?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a small app were the user can create flash cards. At first, I have them create the title, then all titles will be listed, once the user clicks on that title they'll be taken to a different screen where they can create the question and answer.

My *Issue* is that I created a *List* of type *Map* but can't figure out how to add and save to the lists that are created in the maps.

#### Model

```
class Cards {
  //final List<String> question;
  //final List<String> answer;
  //final String title;  
  final String uid;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> classes;

  Cards({ this.uid, this.classes });

}
```

#### Home

This is where it starts, the *elList.add* only runs once when the user creates a title.

```
  Cards indexData = snapshot.data;
 List<Map<String, dynamic>> elList = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < indexData.classes.length; i++) {
           elList.add(indexData.classes[i]);
          }

elList.add({
   "title": title,
   "question": [],
   "answer": [] 
  });                   
    DatabaseService(uid: userId.uid).settingUserData(elList);

  // Send the values to another screen where the user creates Q&A
 MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ViewIndex(                                                                                             
          questions: elList[index]["question"],
          answers: elList[index]["answer"]
                                        ),
                                      ),
```

#### Service

This is where it gets saved to the db. My issue here is trying to figure out how to add on to the lists inside the map because this only adds to the list *classes*, which indexes all the maps. This runs when the title is created. Trying to figure out how to add to lists inside of map and save them? I tried something like: "classes[question]" and "classes.question", but none work.

```
 Future settingUserData(List<Map<String, dynamic>> listCard) async {
    return await _collref.document(uid).setData({  
      "classes": listCard
      });
  }
```

#### ViewIndex

This is where I receive them from the home file as params via the widget. This is where the user creates the questions and answers. Trying to add to them gives me an error, saying they are *fixed-length*. So here is where I also need to save them to the database, but as seen in my service file above, I don't know how to save these separately without having to create a whole new index to the list *classes*, which isn't what I want.

```
widget.answers.add("foo")
widget.questions.add("foo")



 DatabaseService(uid: userId.uid).settingUserData();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe I didn't notice this... But all I needed to do was to add the passed arguments from home to view index AND then move them to an array and loop through them

#### ViewIndex

```
                 List<dynamic> userAnswer = [];
                 List<dynamic> userQuestion = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < widget.questions.length; i++) {
                  userQuestion.add(widget.questions[i]);
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < widget.answers.length; i++) {
                  userAnswer.add(widget.answers[i]);
                }   

   DatabaseService(uid: userId.uid)
            .updattingUserData(widget.index, userQuestion, userAnswer);
```

#### Service

Here I then used dot notation to read and write to that specific list in the maps. I also needed to pass the index to know, well, to know which one I was writing to. I made a separate function for this. The reason it was a fixed length was that I didn't have it in a list.

```
Future updattingUserData(int index, List<dynamic> question, List<dynamic> answer) async {
    return await _collref.document(uid).updateData({
      "classes.$index.questions": FieldValue.arrayUnion(question),
      "classes.$index.answers": FieldValue.arrayUnion(answer)
   });
  }
```

Everything else is exactly the same as I have in my First post.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better solution for you is u define another class for your Classes as a model to become

```
class Cards {
  //final List<String> question;
  //final List<String> answer;
  //final String title;  
  final String uid;
  final List<YourClass> classes;

  Cards(this.uid, this.classes);
}

class YourClass {
  final Map<String, dynamic> yourObject;
  YourClass(this.yourObject);
}
```

Then, initialized yourClass with the object you wanted, and assign it to your Cards.

```
  List<YourClass> classes = List<YourClass>();
  Map<String, dynamic> myItem = jsonDecode('{"hello": "dart","world": {"json": "blabla"}}');

  // create your classItem
  YourClass class1 = YourClass(myItem);

  // add your classItem to a your classes list
  classes.add(class1);

  // add your classes to your card
  Cards card = Cards('myUid', classes);
  print(jsonEncode(card.classes[0].yourObject['hello']));
```

play around here: [example](https://gist.github.com/wish4129/eb9a9392ea35f18e5ba7d7ce90def97d)

Comment: I am using the same set up as above under 'Service' to save it to the DB.

Comment: thanks for a solution but I am still having a bit of trouble. I can't seem to save it to the DB. I keep getting an error: `Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'MapCard'`

Comment: I supposed i can give better advice if I can look at your updated code

Comment: Just to let you know I have tried multiple other ways, for example I tried adding it differently like: "settingUserData(card.classes[].mapClasses)" and  having settingUserData(jsonDecode(jsonEncode(classes))), some stuff I looked online....

Comment: did you update your databaseService to consume MapCard, or still the same of previous of Map<String, dynamic>?

Comment: Are you talking about how I am handling it in the 'Service'? If so, then yes. It's underneath my 'Updated Code'  I have it as List<MapCard>